# Integral of time with respect to Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to compute $\int_0^T t\ dB_t$ where $B$ is the standard Brownian motion.

To this end I define the sequence of simple predictable functions
$$ f_n = \sum_{i=0}^{2^nn-1}t_i^n1_{(t_i^n,t_{i+1}^n]}(t) \quad \text{where} \quad t_i^n = i2^{-n}$$

Then I show that $\lVert f_n-t\rVert_{\mathcal{L}^2(B)} \rightarrow 0$. The convergence in $\mathcal{L}^2(B)$ is equivalent to showing that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E \int_0^m (f_n-t)^2\ d[B]_t = 0 \quad \forall{m} \in \mathbb{N}$$
First, I fix $m$ and choose $n > m$. I also drop the expectation.
\begin{align}E \int_0^m (f_n-t)^2\ d[B]_t \leq&  \int_0^n (f_n-t)^2\ dt\\
= & \frac{1}{3}n2^{-2n} \end{align}
Now I let $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since $m$ was arbitrary, I have convergence in $\mathcal{L}^2(B)$.

Following the definition of stochastic integration of simple predictable processes I write
$$\int_0^Tf_n\ dB_t = \sum_{i=0}^{2^nn-1}t_i^n(B_{T\wedge t_{i+1}^n}-B_{T\wedge t_i^n})$$

I start having problems at this point. I need to get rid of the wedge sign and I do that intuitively. For a given $T$, I choose $n > T$ so that for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^nn-1}t_i^n(B_{T\wedge t_{i+1}^n}-B_{T\wedge t_i^n}) = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}t_i^n(B_{t_{i+1}^n}-B_{t_i^n}) + t_{m}(B_T-B_{t_m^n})$$

Now I let $n$ go to infinity. But I don't see in full rigour how this is the same thing as
setting up a mesh $\pi: 0 = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_r = T$ where $t_i = \frac{iT}{r}$ and letting $r$ go to infinity in 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}t_i(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$$
Because eventually I need to show that the latter sum converges to something in $L^2$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$.

So this was my first question. The second one is how do I show that the sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}t_i(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$$ converges to something (I don't know what that is yet) in $L^2$.
We are given a hint to use summation by parts. So I use the hint to get
$$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}t_i(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i}) = TB_T - \frac{1}{r}\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}B_{t_{i+1}}$$

I have no clue what to do with the second part of this sum.

My apologies if there is any nonsense, gibberish in what I wrote as I myself am confused in this arduous process of learning stochastic calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because of continuity of Brownian motion, it doesn't matter how we choose the partition as long as the mesh size converges to $0$. The continuity of Brownian motion implies that the term 
   $$t_m (B_T-B_{t_m})$$ converges (almost surely and in $L^2$) to $0$ if we let $n \to \infty$. Since we *know* that the result does not depend on the chosen partition, the best choice (regarding notation) is $t_i := \frac{i}{n} T$, $i=0,\ldots,n$,
2. Hint: $$\frac{1}{r} \sum_{i=0}^{r-1} B_{t_{i+1}} = \sum_{i=0}^{r-1} B_{t_{i+1}} (t_{i+1}-t_i).$$ Do you recognize the expression at the right-hand side? Think of $$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} f(t_{i+1}) (t_{i+1}-t_i)$$

Comment: Thank you so much, once again. Your hint for the second question almost looks like the Riemann integral but then wouldn't I need $f(t_i)$ instead of $f(t_{i+1})$? Or it doesn't matter in this case because the integrator, $t$, is smooth? By the way I came up with another answer for the second question (thanks to one of our previous discussions under another question). I will post it in a bit.

Comment: @Calculon "Smooth" is overkill, "continuous" does the job. So: Yes, because of continuity, it doesn't matter whether we use $f(t_i)$ or $f(t_{i+1})$ in the Riemann sum.

Comment: But if continuity were sufficient, then integration wrt Brownian motion would yield the same result regardless of which end point (or intermediate point) we pick, which we know is not true.

Comment: @Calculon Ah, sorry, I was talking about continuity of $f$ (i.e. the integrand; not the integrator!) You are right, if we consider $$\sum f(t_{i+1}) (B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$$ then the limit does not equal the limit of the Riemann sum $$\sum f(t_i) (B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$$ even if $f$ is nice/smooth.

Comment: so then a bit more regularity than continuity is required on the integrator to allow freedom of choice in where we evaluate the integrand?

Comment: @Calculon No, it's not that easy. The point is, basically, that it depends on the type of the integral. If $g$ is a function of bounded variation and $f$ Riemann-Stieltjes integrable (wrt to $g$), then $$\sum_n f(\xi_i) (g(t_{i+1})-g(t_i))$$ converges to $$\int_0^T f(t) \, dg(t)$$ no matter how we choose $\xi_i \in [t_i,t_{i+1}]$. Mind that the Riemann sum $$\sum_i f(t_i) (B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$$ converge in $L^2$ (and not pointwise!) which means that $f$ is not (necessarily) Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to Brownian motion. [...]

Comment: This is because $\int f(t) \, dB_t$ is an Itô-integral, not a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: yes but the sum that we have (the one in your hint I mean) has increments of time, not of Brownian motion. So it is not really Ito integral that we are dealing with here. We can just fix $\omega$ and we have that $B(t,\omega)$ is continuous so the Riemann-Stieltjes integral applies here again.

Comment: @Calculon Yes, that's correct (so here $g(t) := t$). But, in your last comment, you asked about regularity of the integator - and if you want to consider more general integrators, then you have first of all to *define* this type of integral. As long as we consider Riemann-Stieltjes integrals everything is fine.

Comment: You are right. I went overboard there.

Answer (score 3):

For the second question I came up with this answer. We have that for each $r \geq 1$ $$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}t_i(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i}) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{T^3}{6}\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\left(2-\frac{1}{r}\right)\right)$$
Furthermore, $$\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}t_i(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i}) \rightarrow \int_0^Tt\ dB_t \quad \text{in} \quad L^2$$

We have the result that if a sequence of normal random variables $(X_r)_r$ converges to $X$ in distribution, then $X$ is normal as well. We have $L^2$ convergence so weak convergence is implied. So then $\int_0^Tt\ dB_t$ must have a normal distribution for which mean is $0$ and variance is given as 
$$\sigma^2 = \lim_{r\rightarrow\infty} \frac{T^3}{6}\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\left(2-\frac{1}{r}\right) = \frac{T^3}{3}.$$

---

Here is a much easier to way compute the variance.

First of all $\int_0^Tt\ dB_t$ is a martingale. It immediately follows that its mean is $0$. To compute the variance we make use of Ito isometry, i.e. 
$$E\left[\left(\int_0^Tt\ dB_t\right)^2\right] =  E\left[\int_0^Tt^2\ d[B]_t\right] = \frac{T^3}{3}$$

Comment: This is really unnecessary if one wants to compute the variance.

Comment: @Did I understand but I am dealing with this kind of stuff for the first time and whatever answer I come up with, as long as it is correct, helps me build confidence in myself in this field. Obviously, I am trying to learn better ways of solving such problems in the mean time. So please feel free to give your feedback if you want to.

Comment: *Itô isometry* is exactly suited to this.

Comment: @Did Thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yep, nice Edit.